# Angular 9 global event binding

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9

Imagine you have a big enterprise application  and want to have a hook on click when element with css class clicked, you **don't want to edit every single usage of the css class and add Angular directive** since it's a time consuming task and errors are guaranteed.

With jQuery it would look like this:
`$('.btn').on('click', ...);`

However, how can I accomplish this with the use of Angular 9?

Comment: Conceptually this doesn't really make much sense for an angular project.  You should know which components have the buttons you want to target in them and bind on them as part of your component logic.  Otherwise you could always put a click event listener on the body of the document, and check if the event originated from an element that matched your class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest creating a [directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) and then use it across the whole application. For example:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myBtn]'
})
export class MyBtnDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick($event){
        console.info('clicked: ' + $event);
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
<button myBtn class="btn">My button</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, however, it was my first solution to the problem. Then I realized it's not going to work. I updated the question, maybe it can bring more details.

Answer (score -4):

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.btn');
elem.addEventListener('click', function(){});
```